# Strange margin above entire layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

My app uses one activity with a ViewPager to swap fragments for the app pages. Every other fragment works, but for some reason, one of them, my settings fragment, doesn't. The following image illustrates this. The red area is the unwanted margin. The blue area is a toolbar that is defined in the main activity layout - it is always there. The green area is the main ViewPager, also defined in the main activity layout:

[image]

This is what the MainActivity layout looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.MainActivity"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Tab Bar -->
    <com.rentalapp.rentmi.views.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content_pager_tab_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/primary" />

    <!-- Content Pager -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_content_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_content_pager_tab_bar" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is what the Settings fragment looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Log Out"
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How do I fix this unwanted margin? If I remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from the main layout, then every other page gets the notification bar drawn on top of the tab bar, which I do not want.

Comment: I guess it is the statusbar height. Try to play with
`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Comment: Did you try to remove "android:paddingTop="10dp" within TextView and using margin?

Comment: @FranklinHirata Yeah, I have messed with those.

Comment: It might help to set the height of the `ViewPager` element to `match_parent`. The current situation (a `wrap_content` element that contains a `match_parent` element) can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: @Thomas Tried your suggestion, didn't work, but nice catch :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure how, but I was able to fix it by removing the one `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` that I had. Removing that in the past broke everything. Now it fixed it.